# Notepad How to replace different values?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

Is it possible?
Example:

```
type=&quot;0&quot; hp=&quot;403587&quot;
type=&quot;0&quot; hp=&quot;43123&quot;
type=&quot;0&quot; hp=&quot;445234&quot;
```

Is there a way for me to search for "hp="(value) "
and replace all the values to 0 at the same time ??

Comment: What you're looking for is searching and replacing by regular expression. N++ provides that as a search mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press "control h" or click "Search" and then "Replace"

[image]

Comment: Uhmm is there another way?? In the xml file im editing rn there are value that i dont want to set to 0.
Heres a sample code in it:
 neutral = 37281
 passive = 233
 passive = 3743
 passive = 2832
 etc.
how do i set "passive" value to 0 at the same time? cause theres too many of em.

Comment: You question is not clear. I thought you wanted to replace the numbers with zeros. What numbers are you trying to replace?

Comment: there's supposed to be &quot; after "hp = " i tried doing
 hp =&quot;[0-10000] but it didnt work.

Comment: use [0-9]+. This is a regular expression.

Comment: You should check the answer as correct if it meet your standards.

Comment: Sorry, I can't i need atleast 15 reputation to upvote other people answer

Comment: You should still be able to check below the up vote as correct answer if you asked the question. Technically right below the down vote.